# Storing a website's link in MYSQL database and then displaying it in your website as hyperlink

Tags: php, html, mysql

Iam developing a bookmaring web application. Iam storing the bookmarked links in a table. How should I retrieve the bookmarked link so that it is displayed as a hyperlink to the user.
[web application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2vdw.png)

Comment: Just store them as string and then in the HTML use them in the `href` attribute of the link.

Comment: Use `a` HTML tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to display a php variable/array that stores the link of websites in anchor element of HTML that works:

```
print '<a href="'.$row['link'].'"> '.$row['link'].' </a>';
```

Here $row array stores the result of mySQL/mySQLi query that fetches the link of websites from database table.

Answer (score 1):

Just store them as string and then in the HTML use them in the `href` attribute of the link. This is simple fetching data from MySQL with PHP and generating HTML after that. Here is some information about A tag in HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

If the column in your MySQL table where you store the URLs is called 'bookmark_url' (just example) then when you fetch a row datain a PHP variable called `$row` you can use it like this:

```
print '<a href="'.$row['bookmark_url'].'">'.$row['bookmark_url'].'</a>';
```

Comment: print '<a href="'.$row['link'].'"> '.$row['link'].' </a>';

Comment: Great. I updated my answer to match your final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following link http://www.google.com in the variable

```
$linkvar='http://www.google.com';
```

then in case of php

```
echo '<a href='.$linkvar.'>'.$linkvar.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base64 to store a link in database

```
base64_encode($yourlink); //encode for inserting into database
base64_decode($yourlink); //decode for using in link

<a href='<?php echo $yourlink ?>'><?php echo $yourlink ?></a>
```